# Angular Material: How to validate Autocomplete against suggested options?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

We have an autocomplete input with `required` validation. When a user searches for an option by entering a query (but doesn't pick any of the options) then the input is valid, even though it doesn't match any of the suggested options.

What I want to achieve is not permitting the user to post the form unless one of the suggested options is selected. How do I achieve this?

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="pick one" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="form.controls['SELECTBOX_VALUE']">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let option of myOptions | async" [value]="option.name"> <span>{{ option.name }}</span> </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
<small *ngIf="!form.controls['SELECTBOX_VALUE'].valid && form.controls['SELECTBOX_DEGER'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Please select.</small>

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        ... some other fields
        SELECTBOX_VALUE: [null, Validators.required]
    });
```

My filter code for Autocomplate is pretty straight forward:

```
this.form.get('SELECTBOX_VALUE').valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(option => secenek ? this.doFilter(option) : this.options.slice())
        );

doFilter (name: string) {
    return this.myOptions.filter(option =>
        option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For those who may need a similar approach. Here's my solution. I've built a custom validation rule according to my needs.

```js
SELECTBOX_VALUE: [
  null,
  Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    FormCustomValidators.valueSelected(this.myArray),
  ]),
];

export class FormCustomValidators {
  static valueSelected(myArray: any[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      let selectboxValue = c.value;
      let pickedOrNot = myArray.filter(
        (alias) => alias.name === selectboxValue
      );

      if (pickedOrNot.length > 0) {
        // everything's fine. return no error. therefore it's null.
        return null;
      } else {
        //there's no matching selectboxvalue selected. so return match error.
        return { match: true };
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method with a slight modification because my array of values were initialized later from an Observable. My version passes in a function instead of an array like: `static valueSelected<T>(exists: (value: T) => boolean): ValidatorFn ` and the condition becomes `if(exists(selectedboxValue)) {`

Comment: You could actually use `some` instead of `filter`, so it return a boolean saying if there is a mathc or not (which is exactly what you are looking for). just replace "filter" by "some", and the if becomes `if (pickedOrNot) {`

Comment: @JeanMarois I have the same situation as yours but I haven't understood your proposed solution : the selectbox_value is part of a form which is defined in the constructor of a component. I don't know at that stage the list of options, that is coming later as the result of a service which is returning an observable list...so how can I "wait" to pass the list of options until I have it?

Comment: @Nicola I posted this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854455/2562746 with some example code. It's not tested, so try it and feel free to ask questions in the answer.

Answer (score 15):

There are two scenarios with [Angular Material Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) that may need to be validated against a list of selected options:

1. **Array of strings** - Suggested options are defined in an array of strings
2. **Array of Objects** - Suggested options are an object property defined on an array of Objects (In this scenario, `displayWith` Input would be used.)

** [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-validation-example.ts) **

## Validate Options from Array of strings

To validate `autocomplete` against an array of string options, the validator may accept the array of options and check if the control value is included.

```js
function autocompleteStringValidator(validOptions: Array<string>): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (validOptions.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
      return null  /* valid option selected */
    }
    return { 'invalidAutocompleteString': { value: control.value } }
  }
}
```

The validator could be added to a `FormControl` along with other built-in validators such as `Validators.required`:

```js
public autocompleteControl = new FormControl('', 
      { validators: [autocompleteStringValidator(this.options), Validators.required] })
```

## Validate Options from Array of Objects

To validate `autocomplete` against an array of object options, the validator can leverage the fact that the `control.value` will only be a `string` if a valid `Object` option has not been selected.

```js
function autocompleteObjectValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (typeof control.value === 'string') {
      return { 'invalidAutocompleteObject': { value: control.value } }
    }
    return null  /* valid option selected */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that validates the selected option against an array obtained from an observable.

```
export class FormCustomValidators {
  static valueSelected<T>(exists: (value: T) => boolean): ValidatorFn {

    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      let selectboxValue = c.value;

      if (exists(selectboxValue)) {
        // everything's fine. return no error. therefore it's null.
        return null;
      } else {
        //there's no matching selectboxvalue selected. so return match error.
        return { 'match': true };
      }
    }
  }
}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myObjects: MyObject[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, FormCustomValidators.valueSelected<MyObject>(this.myObjectExists.bind(this))]));
    this.service.getMyObjects().subscribe((myObjects) => {
      this.myObjects = myObjects
    }
  }
  
  private myObjectExists(value): boolean {
    return this.myObjects.some(v => v === value);
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

You can add on your Submit function a validation check for the fields,

```
Submit() {
 if(this.form.valid) {
   // send to API
 } else {
   // show error
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this inside html. Do you think there's no way of this?

Comment: you can disable the submit button, [disabled]="!form.valid"

Comment: but I as mentioned in the original question, form is always valid because validation mechanism only checks for requirement of whatever string value of selectbox. so I do not think [disabled]="!form.valid" would work.