# Angular Material Autocomplete Using An Array<Object>

Tags: angular, filter, autocomplete, angular-material

I have the following Stackblitz:
[AutoComplete - StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ig444e?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Once a user selects an option, then clears the input and starts typing, the filtering stops working.

How can a user select an option and start typing where only the valid results show?

Comment: Can u create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Here is the stackblitz https://angular-material-autocomplete-eg-f1e8wk.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stops working because you're getting an error in rxjs stream.

`value` can be a `string` or `option` object. You have to properly map it through `map` operator:

Instead of

```
.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this._filter(value))
);
```

try the following:

```
.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.address),
  map(address => address ? this._filter(address) : this.options.slice())
);
```

**[Forker Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-7rfnkq?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts)**

See also ***Display value autocomplete*** example in [Angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)

### Update

OP thinks that this implementation has an issue:

> I forked off yours again and added a button just for ease. If you
> select an option, click continue, backspace the "0" from the zip code,
> click continue, add the zero back to the input, click continue. This
> gives you undefined https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-4w15ki?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html

But if you check material docs it works as expected because there is no select on match or force selection feature in Angular material autocomplete https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3334

This means that if you're typing and typed string matches exactly with value in autocomplete then FormControl value will be still string not object as you expected.

In order to force it you can create a simple directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[forceSelection]"
})
export class AutocompleteForceSelectionDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  @Input('forceSelection') key: string;

  private destroyed$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    @Host() @Self() private autoCompleteTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger,
    private ngControl: NgControl
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.autoCompleteTrigger.panelClosingActions
      .pipe(
        filter(e => !e || !e.source),
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe(e => {
        const selected = this.matAutocomplete.options
          .map(option => option.value)
          .find(option => (this.key ? option[this.key] : option) === this.ngControl.value);

        if (selected) {
          this.ngControl.control.setValue(selected);
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
  }
}
```

And apply it to your input

```
<input ... [matAutocomplete]="auto" forceSelection="address">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-lih2bo?file=app%2Fautocomplete-force-selection.directive.ts

Comment: That seems to work. Although I am going to play with it a bit more to make sure I understand, I marked it as the answer.

Comment: On second look, there is an issue when you select an option, then backspace any part of the input address and retype it manually without selecting the option `this.myControl.value.id` will come back as `undefined`

Comment: I forked off yours again and added a button just for ease. If you select an option, click continue, backspace the "0" from the zip code, click continue, add the zero back to the input, click continue. This gives you `undefined` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-4w15ki?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html

Comment: I updated the answer. You can check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-lih2bo?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html

Comment: 1. Thank-you for writing that up I was able to incorporate, 2. I can't believe angular doesn't have a better way to do this. 3. I have one last piece left and that is the form validation piece. I added `property.dirty && property.errors?.required` to a div, but any suggestions on how I could populate an invalid message when the option doesn't match in this case (this would be separate from the required message and only show when the field is dirty and the field is not violating the required validator)? - Maybe a custom validator?

Comment: Yes, you can implement a custom validator like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871720/angular-material-how-to-validate-autocomplete-against-suggested-options