# How to validade an input with Angular Autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, mat-error

I need some help.

I'm using Angular Material.

My issue is about the mat-error show/off when using autocomplete.

In my code, I have a form with an autocomplete input. The input calls a JSON object as a response.

```
{ name: 'Paul', id: 1 }
```

At this point a need to show [name], when selected on the select option, in the input. And set the option value to [id].

No problem, I've done with.

> [displayWith]="displayFn"

That's ok, everything works as should, but I don't know how to validate the [id] as a number. Every time I've tried it just validate the input [name] as a string.

Why I need that? So, I will use just the [id] to build the form object [ownerId].

```html
<input id="ownerId" type="text" matInput formControlName="ownerId" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Digite para pesquisar..." name="doNotAutocomplete" autocomplete="doNotAutoComplete" required>
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of owners" [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
<mat-error>Selecione ou cadastre um novo proprietário.</mat-error>
```

```js
    // Set display owner name on input form - id on value
    displayFn(owner: Owner): any {
        return owner && owner.name ? owner.name : '';
    }
```

```js
        // Horizontal Stepper form steps
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    ownerId: ['', [Validators.required],
                    code: ['', Validators.required],
                    agent: ['', Validators.required]
                }),
```

The mat-error is setting the input INVALID when the name is selected from the input.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: If you find a solution, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) - don't edit the solution into the question

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution,

Here in Stackoverflow, I have found a solution approach: Angular Material: [How to validate Autocomplete against suggested options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871720/angular-material-how-to-validate-autocomplete-against-suggested-options)

What was needed is simple, I had to create and custom validator function such as:

```
function ownerIdValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (typeof control.value === 'string') {
      return { 'invalidAutocompleteObject': { value: control.value } };
    }

    return null;  /* valid option selected */
  };
}
```

And added here:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
       ownerId: ['', [Validators.required, ownerIdValidator()]],
```

I hope it could help someone else.